# PayPal Payment Pro - definitive answer on which field should be used to identify the order

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am implementing PayPal payments pro for a client at the moment, and therefore I am configuring the IPN service to confirm the purchase on the clients server. What I can't work out is which field should be used to "carry" the id of the order to be passed back to the IPN handler?

Some say the invoice field, and some say the custom field...

What is the best practice? (if there is one)

I know there are some similar questions out there, but I am looking for a definitive best practice answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what the invoice field is for. That is best practice.

With at least some of their products PayPal also applies duplicate-payment testing based on invoice but not on custom. This is usually a good reason to put your unique order identifier in the invoice field (you don't want a user to pay for the same purchase twice) but if, for some reason, this doesn't mesh with how you handle order IDs then you could put your order ID in the unmanaged (by paypal) custom field.

Comment: Thank you, maybe it's just me, but the Paypal documentation seems a little unclear. My program assigns the order id prior to payment, so there will be no confusion. Also didn't realise the invoice field was checked for duplicates, so that will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is Invoice field, just be aware with the possibility of Invoice locking - prevents someone from paying for the same invoice twice.

For example two people checkout at the same time, you pass Paypal the next invoice id - so both users are attempting to pay for the same invoice. After one person completes the transaction the other one will get duplicate invoice error.